# How to make two similar dropdowns in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am learning to make drop-down using values from sql tables.

I have two drop-downs: Family member and Dzongkhag. The first one is working, but 2nd drop-down is not working. I have used the same code in the 2nd drop-drown, but it does not work.

#### Attempt

```
enter<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  `enter code here`<title>Add Record Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="addlandac.php" method="post">
    <p>
    <label for="plotno">Plot no:</label>
    <input type="text" name="plotno" id="plotno">
    <label for="thramno">Thram No:</label>
    <input type="text" name="thramno" id="thramno">

 <label for="familyname">Name of family:</label>
 <?php include("config_qc.php");

  $query="SELECT * FROM familymember_tbl";
 $result =mysqli_query($connect,$query);
 $options="";
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

 $famid=$row["familyID"];
 $nam=$row["name"];
//$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$dzong\">".$dzong.'-'.$dz_id.'</option>';
$options.="<OPTION VALUE>".$nam.'-'.$famid.'</option>';

}
?>
 <select name="family" id="family">
<option value="Select">Select family member</option>
<?=$options?>

//</p>
//<p>

 <label for="dz">Dzonkhag:</label>
<?php include("config_qc.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM dzongkhag_tbl";
$result =mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$opt="";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$dz_id=$row["dzID"];
$dzong=$row["dzname"];
//$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$dzong\">".$dzong.'-'.$dz_id.'</option>';
$opt.="<OPTION VALUE>".$dzong.'-'.$dz_id.'</option>';
}
?>
 <select name="dz" id="dz">
 <option value="Select">Select Dzongkhag</option>
 <?=$opt?>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit">

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>

 <?php
 echo "<BR>";
 echo"<h4 align=left </h4>";
echo "<BR>";
 echo "<a href='menu.php'>Bac to Main page</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Please define "not working" is it throwing errors? Or is your select empty. Is there data in your table? Is the code in the same file? If it is in the same file try removing the second `include`.

Comment: This reply to Sir Pilan.     Not working , I mean it is not showing Any drop-drop for selection. Yes it is same page. It is working  if test in different page. Ye s there is data in the tables. thank you

Comment: As i mentioned, try removing the second `include`

Comment: Plan Sir, Removed The second include. But it still not working

Comment: I have removed include. But still then not working

Comment: Hard to tell whats wrong. Can you post the entire code including the include.

Comment: Pilan Sir. I could not send entire code, as there was error while im tying to upload.
However, I am giving you the this  link so that sir could understand  my problem       http://sangpo.store/addlandform.php

Comment: What*s the exact problem? Have you checked whether the generated markup looks like the one you would expect? Is there any error message given by a HTML validator? Is there any error message given by your browser?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Get rid of ANYTHING which is not relevant for the problem. Will help you find the error aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe you are missing some close `</select>` tags. Maybe, try something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Add Record Form</title>
    </head>
   <body>
       <form action="addlandac.php" method="post">
            <label for="plotno">Plot no:</label>
            <input type="text" name="plotno" id="plotno">
            <label for="thramno">Thram No:</label>
            <input type="text" name="thramno" id="thramno">

            <label for="familyname">Name of family:</label>
            <?php include("config_qc.php");

            $query="SELECT * FROM familymember_tbl";
            $result =mysqli_query($connect,$query);
            $options="";
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $famid=$row["familyID"];
                $nam=$row["name"];
                $options.="<OPTION VALUE>".$nam.'-'.$famid.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            <select name="family" id="family">
                <option value="Select">Select family member</option>
                <?=$options?>
            </select>

             <label for="dz">Dzonkhag:</label>
            <?php include("config_qc.php");
            $query="SELECT * FROM dzongkhag_tbl";
            $result =mysqli_query($connect,$query);
            $opt="";
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $dz_id=$row["dzID"];
                $dzong=$row["dzname"];
                $opt.="<OPTION VALUE>".$dzong.'-'.$dz_id.'</option>';
            }
            ?>

            <select name="dz" id="dz">
                <option value="Select">Select Dzongkhag</option>
                <?=$opt?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

         </form>

        <?php
        echo "<BR>";
        echo"<h4 align=left </h4>";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "<a href='menu.php'>Bac to Main page</a>";
        ?>
     </body>
 </html>
```

or something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Add Record Form</title>
    </head>
   <body>
       <form action="addlandac.php" method="post">
            <label for="plotno">Plot no:</label>
            <input type="text" name="plotno" id="plotno">
            <label for="thramno">Thram No:</label>
            <input type="text" name="thramno" id="thramno">

            <label for="familyname">Name of family:</label>
            <?php 
                include("config_qc.php");

                $query="SELECT * FROM familymember_tbl";
                $result =mysqli_query($connect,$query);
                $options="";
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    $famid=$row["familyID"];
                    $nam=$row["name"];
                    $options.="<option value="'.$nam.'-'.$famid.'">"'.$nam.'-'.$famid.'"</option>";
                }
            ?>
            <select name="family" id="family">
                <option value="Select family member">Select family member</option>
                <?=$options?>
            </select>

             <label for="dz">Dzonkhag:</label>
            <?php 
                include("config_qc.php");
                $query="SELECT * FROM dzongkhag_tbl";
                $result =mysqli_query($connect,$query);
                $opt="";
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    $dz_id=$row["dzID"];
                    $dzong=$row["dzname"];
                    $opt.="<option value="'.$dzong.'-'.$dz_id.'">"'.$dzong.'-'.$dz_id.'"</option>";
                }
            ?>

            <select name="dz" id="dz">
                <option value="Select Dzongkhag">Select Dzongkhag</option>
                <?=$opt?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

         </form>

        <?php echo "<br><h4 align=left </h4><br><a href='menu.php'>Back to main page</a>"; ?>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Sir Emma and others, Thank u a lot for editing my code. Now it is working exactly as I wanted.